# Whats the syntax of making a string value generic inside something.execute(String[],String) with groovy inside build.gradle file?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradlew

Below is the command cmd that is going to get executed and is working fine.

```
def process = cmd.execute(['PATH=D:/Project/Node_Project/build/nodejs/node-v10.10.0-win-x64'],null)
```

`"D:/Project/Node_Project"` is my project root folder.

I am trying something like below to make the path generic but it didn't work. ${project.buildDir} also didn't work.

```
def process = cmd.execute(['PATH=${project.projectDir}/build/nodejs/node-v10.10.0-win-x64'],null)
```

I want to know what is the correct format to make it generic.

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#execute(java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)

The above link contains the documentation for the syntax only but no examples to solve my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by making it generic? If you want to use string interpolation, you'll have to use double quotes

Comment: Yes.. I want to know that string interpolation syntax in this case. I tried double quotes previously. That didn't work.
By generic I meant, the variable {project.projectDir} (I don't know if it is the correct one) should pick up the project root directory to frame the PATH string name.

Comment: For starters, you need to do this (with double quotes) `"PATH=${project.projectDir}/build/nodejs/node-v10.10.0-win-x64"` instead of what you have (single quotes) because single quoted strings don't support string interpolation - they're like plain Java strings

Comment: Thank you..
`def process = cmd.execute(["PATH=${project.projectDir}/build/nodejs/node-v10.10.0-win-x64"],null)`
This worked.
Is there any way to make the rest of the path _"build/nodejs/node-v10.10.0-win-x64"_ generic?

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by generic. Do you mean that you want it to be a parameter to some method?

Comment: I downloaded node using
`node {
    download = true
    version = "10.10.0"
    workDir = file("${project.buildDir}/nodejs")
}`
So, I dont want to hardcode `"build/nodejs/node-v10.10.0-win-x64"` in the path value and want to fetch the value of **node.exe** path (which is inside `${project.projectDir}/build/nodejs/node-v10.10.0-win-x64`) to the environment variable path through cmd.execute() .
Is it possible?

Comment: For instance something like:


`def process = cmd.execute(["PATH=${project.projectDir}/build/nodejs/*"],null)`

Comment: I honestly don't know about that stuff, you should probably edit your question to make your purpose clearer so someone who knows about that can help you

Comment: I have made a separate question for that..
https://stackoverflow.com/q/62382667/12930288