# Is there any way to automatically setting windows path in a string in groovy?

Tags: java, node.js, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

My project root directory is:

```
D:/Project/Node_Project
```

I am using a gradle plugin to install nodejs temporarily in my project root directory so that some nodejs command can run in the project while the thoject builds. The plugin is as below:

```
plugins {
    id "com.github.node-gradle.node" version "2.2.4"
}
node {
    download = true
    version = "10.10.0"
    distBaseUrl = 'https://nodejs.org/dist'
    workDir = file("${project.buildDir}/nodejs")
}
```

So, nodejs is getting installed inside the project in the location:

```
D:/Project/Node_Project/build/nodejs/node-v10.10.0-win-x64
```

Now, I am using a `.execute(String[] "path to set at environment variable", String path of file to be executed which is in the project root directory)` method to run a windows command with node dependency. Code below:

```
cmd = "node connect.js"
def process = cmd.execute(["PATH=${project.projectDir}/build/nodejs/node-v10.10.0-win-x64"],null)
```

In the above .execute method, is there a way to auto-populate the `"build/nodejs/node-v10.10.0-win-x64"` part of the string instead of hardcoding it into the method?
Something like:

```
def process = cmd.execute(["PATH=${project.projectDir}/.*"],null)
```

Syntax of .execute method:
https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#execute(java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)

All the codes are inside "build.gradle" file. Please help!

Comment: Is there a reason for not using the [NodeTask](https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/docs/usage.md#running-a-nodejs-script) type for running your scripts?

Answer (score 0):

I asked why you don't just write a task of type [NodeTask](https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/docs/usage.md#running-a-nodejs-script), but I understand that you like to run a it in the background, which you can't do with that.

You could list the content of a directory and use that as part of the command. But you could also just grab it from the extension provided by the plugin.

This is not documented and it might break in future releases of the plugin, but you can do something like this (Groovy DSL):

```
task connectJS {
    dependsOn nodeSetup
    doFirst {
        def connectProcess = "$node.variant.nodeExec $projectDir/src/js/connect.js".execute()
        // Blocking readers (if async, pipe to a log file instead)
        connectProcess.in.eachLine { logger.info(it) }
        connectProcess.err.eachLine { logger.err(it) }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand your point.. But I didnt use node task because of the following issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/62304898/12930288
Thank you for reaching out!

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear. This is not using the node task - it is using the nodeSetup task to download Node and then the Groovy process builder for executing a command using the node executable _path_ from the setup task. This can be executed done in the background (if you remove the logger lines from the example).

Comment: Thank you..
`def connectProcess = "$node.variant.nodeExec $projectDir/connect.js".execute()`
This solved my purpose.. :)